# Combine two DataFrames pairwise with a binary function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables of the same dimensions and want to make the third where each cell if the result of applying a binary function to corresponding cells of those two tables. For example:

```
$ t1
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

$ t2
array([["A", "B"],
       ["C", "D"]])

$ combine(t1, t2, lambda x, y: "{}-{}".format(x, y))
array([["0-A", "1-B"],
       ["2-C", "3-D"]])
```

In other words, I want a generalized version of element-wise operations like add, div, etc. Sounds like a simple task, yet I couldn't find anywhere how to do this easily.

Comment: please provide small (3-5 rows) sample input data sets and your desired data set...

Comment: @MaxU added one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the columns have the same name, you can use `df.apply`.

```
df1.apply(lambda x: binary_function(x, df2[x.name]))
```

---

```
df1
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3

df2
   0  1
0  A  B
1  C  D

df1.astype(str) + '-' + df2
     0    1
0  0-A  1-B
1  2-C  3-D
```

More generally:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str) + '-' + df2[x.name])
     0    1
0  0-A  1-B
1  2-C  3-D
```

Using `str.format`:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: ['{}-{}'.format(k, y) for  k, y in zip(x, df2[x.name].values)])
     0    1
0  0-A  1-B
1  2-C  3-D
```

Comment: This combines rows, not cells!

Comment: @Yuuri I've edited my answer to include the data from your example. I'm not sure what more you'd want from this.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Seems you have changed the binary function used in the example so it could work with series rather than scalar cells. With .format it doesn't work.

Comment: @Yuuri I'm sorry but it makes no sense to do that. You can either apply one column at a time using apply, or one row at a time using apply. One element at a time seems pointless.

Comment: @Yuuri See edit. You should understand that you're abusing pandas and throwing away all speed and efficiency benefits.

Comment: @Coldspeed thank you, the last snippet looks more like what I desire. I can sacrifice some efficiency for the sake of versatility and reusability. I'll test and accept the answer tomorrow, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Demo for DFs with non-aligned indices and columns:

Setup:

```
In [26]: d1 = pd.DataFrame(t1)

In [27]: d2 = pd.DataFrame(t2, index=[3,5], columns=['a','b'])

In [28]: d1
Out[28]:
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3

In [29]: d2
Out[29]:
   a  b
3  A  B
5  C  D
```

Solution:

```
In [30]: d1.astype(str).add('-').add(d2.values)
Out[30]:
     0    1
0  0-A  1-B
1  2-C  3-D
```